# Pointer/pointer variable assigning and printing output

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, function-definition

I am pretty new to pointers in C and I had a practice question and I do not understand why the answer is what it is. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void changeValue(int *valuePassed)
{
    *valuePassed = 100;
}

int main()
{
    int testValue = 9;
    changeValue(&testValue);
    printf("%d\n", testValue);
}
```

This ends up printing 100 and I am not sure why.

First, is the function changeValue being passed a pointer variable or is it being passed the value at address valuePassed (from what I know, these are two different things). Second, the line *valuePassed = 100 is setting the value at the location of valuePassed to 100, correct? But valuePassed has not been assigned an address. So  if the address of testValue (&testValue) is passed into the changeValue function, how is 100 being printed?

Comment: `*valuePassed = 100;` kind of guarantees that it will print `100` what did you expect?  passing the _address of` operator allows the function to modify the _value_ residing at that address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, is the function changeValue being passed a pointer variable or
>   is it being passed the value at address valuePassed (from what I know,
>   these are two different things)

There is passed the address of the variable `testValue`

```
changeValue(&testValue);
```

that is assigned to the pointer variable `valuePassed` that is a parameter of the function and at the same time a local variable of the function..

```
void changeValue(int *valuePassed)
```

You can imagine the function call and the function definition the following way

```
changeValue(&testValue);

//...

void changeValue( /* int *valuePassed */ )
{
    int * valuePassed = &testValue;
    *valuePassed = 100;
}
```

> But valuePassed has not been assigned an address.

You are wrong. As you can see above it was assigned by the address of the variable `testValue`.

> So if the address of testValue (&testValue) is passed into the
>   changeValue function, how is 100 being printed?

Th integer constant `100` is not pointed. It is the variable `testValue` that is pointed and to its pointed memory that is where the variable is defined the integer constant 100 is stored.

In the terms of C passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it is called passing by reference.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types, p.#20)

> — A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object
>   type, called the referenced type. **A pointer type describes an object
>   whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced
>   type.** A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes
>   called ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a pointer type from a
>   referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. A pointer type
>   is a complete object type.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, but how did you obtain the function call/definition that way? That's what was throwing me off, I didn't know that int *valuePassed = &testValue when &testValue is passed to the function, I thought it was subbing in one for the other. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @cmting17 There is no such a function definition. But under the hood  the parameter of the function is initialized by the value of the passed expression used as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

> is the function changeValue being passed a pointer variable or is it being passed the value at address valuePassed

*&testValue* is the address of the variable *valuePassed*

> *valuePassed = 100 is setting the value at the location of valuePassed to 100, correct?

"*valuePassed = 100;*" changes the value of the variable *valuePassed*, but here because of the "***" the form "**valuePassed = 100;*" modifies the value whose address is memorized in  *valuePassed*. Because *valuePassed* values the address of *valuePassed* the assignment modifies the value of *valuePassed* to be 100

> ```
>  printf("%d\n", testValue);
> ```

prints 100 being the current value of *testValue*

That is the goal of the pointers

Answer (score 0):

> So if the address of testValue (&testValue) is passed into the changeValue function, how is 100 being printed?

The magic happen here is because of two things:

1. `valuePassed` was assigned by the address of `testValue` in the call to `changeValue()` as `valuePassed`:

```
changeValue(&testValue);
```

Note, that `&` yields the address of an object.

2. The `*` dereference operator in:

```
    *valuePassed = 100;
```

This operator dereferences the pointer `valuePassed`. Means it access the object `valuePassed` points to.

In this way, `100` gets assigned to the object `testValue` inside of `main()` and `100` is printed by the call to `printf()` thereafter.